# Transpose from row to column

Tags: bash, awk

Traspose from line to column is the objetive, taking in consideration the first column, which is the date

**Input file**

```
72918,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009
72918,2356,2357,2358,2359,2360,2361,2362,2363,2364
72918,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
72918,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
72918,1496,1502,1752,1752,1752,1752,1751,974,972
73018,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009,111000009
73018,2349,2350,2351,2352,2353,2354,2355,2356,2357
73018,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
73018,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
73018,1524,1526,1752,1752,1752,1752,1752,256,250
```

**Output desired**

```
72918,111000009,2356,0,0,1496
72918,111000009,2357,0,0,1502
72918,111000009,2358,0,0,1752
72918,111000009,2359,0,0,1752
72918,111000009,2360,0,0,1752
72918,111000009,2361,0,0,1752
72918,111000009,2362,0,1,1751
72918,111000009,2363,0,0,974
72918,111000009,2364,0,0,972
73018,111000009,2349,0,0,1524
73018,111000009,2350,0,0,1526
73018,111000009,2351,0,0,1752
73018,111000009,2352,0,0,1752
73018,111000009,2353,0,0,1752
73018,111000009,2354,0,0,1752
73018,111000009,2355,0,0,1752
73018,111000009,2356,0,0,256
73018,111000009,2357,0,0,250
```

Please advise, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: OXXO, you should see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to do exactly what you need:

```
awk -F, '
 func init_block() {ts=$1;delete a;cnt=0;nf0=NF}
 func dump_block() {for(f=2;f<=nf0;f+=1){printf("%s",ts);for(r=1;r<=cnt;r+=1){printf(",%s",a[r,f])};print ""}}
 BEGIN{ts=-1}
 ts<0{init_block()}
 ts!=$1{dump_block();init_block()}
 {cnt+=1;for(f=1; f<=NF; f++) a[cnt,f]=$f}
 END{dump_block()}' <input.txt >output.txt
```

It collects rows until the timestamp changes, then prints the transpose of the block with keeping the same timestamp. The number of fields in the input must be the same within each block so that this code behaves correctly.